# Blazor/WPF: Add input line and select line to forms with button click

Tags: html, wpf, blazor

I want to add a new...

```
<input type="text" id="id_item1" name="item1" @bind="@inputValue1" @oninput="OnInputEvent1" ><br>
```

...to my form by clicking a button.
There's a second form, with a `<select>` and `<option>`, which also needs to increment by clicking the same button:

```
<select name="categories" id="cat1" size="1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>- Choose a category -</option>
    <option value="Fruits & vegetables">Fruits & vegetables</option>
    <option value="Baked goods">Baked goods</option>
    <option value="Meat & fish">Meat & fish</option>
    <option value="Dry foods">Dry foods</option>
    <option value="Dairy products">Dairy products</option>
    <option value="Candy & snacks">Candy & snacks</option>
    <option value="Beverages">Beverages</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know about WPF, can't you use `@foreach(var item in inputList)` and add an object in the list every time you click the button?

Comment: What have you tried or is this some sort of test for us? Most of us here like solving problems but we are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: I think this bit is blazor and a collection of products in the model is the usual way to do this. A more sophisticated approach than the @code used elsewhere is advisable imo.